# カメラのホワイトバランスをマニュアルと赤、青バランス設定にしたい。

Tags: spresense

ご担当者様
multi_webcamera参考にしてwindowsとmjpegのソフトを開発しています。
ret = multiwebcam_set_ext_ctrls(v_fd, V4L2_CTRL_CLASS_CAMERA,
V4L2_CID_AUTO_N_PRESET_WHITE_BALANCE,
V4L2_WHITE_BALANCE_FLUORESCENT);
上記のサンプルプログラムでV4L2_WHITE_BALANCE_MANUALにしましたがret=-1のエラーになります。

V4L2_WHITE_BALANCE_MANUAL、V4L2_CID_RED_BALANCE、V4L2_CID_BLUE_BALANCEの設定方法（関数コール）を教えて頂けないでしょうか？
宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

Manual設定、Red、Blueバランス設定が自己解決できました。
お騒がせしました。

Comment: 情報共有のために、何を如何したのかの詳細を具体的に記述してもらえませんか？